# Transfer songs from ipod nano without password

Tags: ipod

I have an old ipod with a lot of songs my son loaded years ago. We cant figure out how to get the songs off the ipod and onto my itunes account.    Can anyone help with this

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put them onto your iTunes account, but you can put them into your iTunes Library with iExplorer or iFunbox.